# Apache - Redirect /folder to /folder/index.php using .htaccess

Tags: apache, redirect, directory, url-rewriting, invisible

when somebody visits

`http://127.0.0.1/something`

I want to redirect him to

`http://127.0.0.1/something/index.php`

using .htaccess.

1. How can I do that?
2. Is it possible to do that without showing the user that they got redirected, like YouTube does (YouTube.com/user/channel/videos/)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found out how to do it.

Warning: I have no experience with mod_rewrite, so this may not be the best solution. It works for me though.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUESTFILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Im a bit late, but shouldnt be ``REQUESTFILENAME`` not ``REQUEST_FILENAME``